# saveVideo only printing out the first image in a video

Tags: r, loops, video

I'm trying to make a video of plots that are output from a loop using saveVideo. However, at the moment the output video only gives the first image for the number of times that the loop runs (40 seconds in my example code). Probably something really obvious, but does anyone know how to fix this?
Example code:

```
create_photos <- function(){
  for (i in 1:40){
    plot(c(0, 1), c(0, 1), ann = F, bty = 'n', type = 'n', xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
    text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, paste(i))
  }
}
saveVideo(create_photos(), video.name = 'animation.mp4')
```

Comment: Have you tried `c(0, i)` instead of `c(0, 1)` (two times!)?

Comment: c(0,1) just gives the plot size, so its needed twice (x and y dimensions).

Comment: Yeah ok, this was the only obvious guess I could take. I don't have any guesses left for that :/

Comment: I was able to reproduce the video with no issue. Just to make sure, do you have imagemagick installed?

Comment: yeh I have imagemagick installed, have been able to use convert from imagemagick before in R

Comment: just to be clear the video I was hoping to get was a frame for each number 1:40, at the moment I just get '1' 40 times